Density changes of 3D projections of spacetime in relativity theory?
In relativity theory, the metric tensor $$g_{\mu\nu} $$ describes the gravitational field.
Can one treat the determinant of the metric tensor, normalized by the square of the Jacobian of the transformation of Minkowski spacetime from a (gauge) cartesian coordinate system to the used coordinate system $$ \frac{|g_{\mu\nu} (x)|} {|J_4(c\rightarrow x)|^2} $$ with n, m = 0..3 as the volume of spacetime and
$$\frac {|g_{ij}|} {|J_3(c \rightarrow x)|^2} $$ with i, j = 1,2,3 as the volume of space, the 3D projection of the 4D spacetime?
And, furthermore, can one treat the gravitational field as density changes of such 3D projections, where the exact direction of the projection is dependent on velocity following the rules of special relativity?

For useful info on this subject see the top answer to Calculating the determinant of a metric tensor.

This part(?) : "But the metric itself (as opposed to its derivatives) doesn't let you compute a curvature, and therefore any such quantity that doesn't involve a derivative cannot be an observable."?

Density changes => derivative of the metric.

you may want to look at my previous post https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/826318/303640
